# How to put an image on another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image and I want to put another image with transparent background on it.
Is there any simple solution with jquery or something? I dont wanna fight with positions etc
I need to add it dynamically for example after clicking something

Comment: You will 'fight with positions' one way or another...

Comment: So you don't want to "fight with positions" but you're happy to use jquery? What's wrong with positions...they're easier than JQ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it needs to be added in a dynamic way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/gcvsz9cm/

Answer (score 3):

create a div and use one image as back-ground image. now put your image inside that div.

Comment: Thats some idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="background"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Image" onclick="show();" />
```

**CSS:**

```
div { background-image: url('path/to/background.filetype'); height: 200px;}
img { opacity: 0.5; }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById('background').innerHTML = '<img src="path/to/image.filetype" />';
}
```

You need to clarify what you mean by 'dynamic', but this is a dynamic way of adding the image using JavaScript (with the graphical properties you described).

Comment: Thank you, but i have to do this in a dynamic way

Comment: In what way 'dynamic'?

Answer (score 1):

this is how you would add an image dynamically on click. hope it helps

```js
$("#flowers").click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var current = _this.attr("src");
  var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
  _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);
  _this.toggleClass("opaque");
});
```

```css
.opaque {
    opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='flowers' src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg' width="500" height="400" data-swap='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg' width="500" height="400" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately i forgot to mention that i need to put the second one in a dynamic way after onclick

Answer (score 1):

added filter: alpha(opacity=60) for IE8 or earlier browsers

just change the background properties to a picture link

```css
.background_picture {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.front_picture {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.6; /* change this to 1 to completely hide background_picture */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_picture">
    <div class="front_picture">
    </div>
</div>
```